# Pandas: Fill and merge two different data-frames based on condition in index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrame, the first one is NYC taxis data set in January contain (10678070 rows and 7 columns), the second is NYC weather data set, also for January ( 864 rows and 30 columns) for each hours as following:

**df2.head()**

[image: NYC taxis DataFrame]

**weather.head()**

[image: NYC weather DataFrame]

So now, what I want to do is merge the two dataframes or add a `weather` columns details to df2 based on trip date and time is equal or less than weather record.
So that, if Column (tpep_pickup_datetime) in df2 is matching or less than (tpep_pickup_datetime) in weather , value the rows from weather are appended to the corresponding row in df2.
I tried that by using the `merge` function (merge_asof), like this:

```py
import pandas


# Sort data before merge then merge
df2.sort_values(by='tpep_pickup_datetime', inplace=True)
weather.sort_values(by='tpep_pickup_datetime', inplace=True)
dmerge=pandas.merge_asof(df2,weather, on="tpep_pickup_datetime", tolerance=pandas.Timedelta('31m'))
```

But I get df2 with NAN values in weather columns, like this:

**dmerge.head()**

[image]

Is there a smooth way to do this in pandas?
Thanks for all in advance!

Comment: Try a larger `Timedelta`

Comment: I'm tried with Timedelta('31m'), and other option like (10-15-45-60), but I get same  result.

Comment: i meant more like `Timedelta('1h')`

Comment: sorry, same result, I don't know how can solve it,,,,